# Getting NHibernate Select N+1

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I am new to NHibernate. I am getting Select N+1 warning when i test my query from NHibernate Profiler. I am not sure what am i doing wrong with my mapping or query.

Basically I have a table called Header and it has got many Details. For each Detail i have a Replay. i.e

one Header-> many Detail
one Detail -> one Replay

Query:

```
    var query = _session.QueryOver(() => headerAlias)
                    .Where(() => headerAlias.ScriptNumber == scriptId)
                    .And(() => headerAlias.ChannelCode == channelId)
                    .Future<ProgramHeader>();
```

My mapping:

```
public ProgramHeaderMap()
{
    Table("S_IDB_M_PROG_HDR");

    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ScriptNumber, "PROGCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ChannelCode, "CHCD");

    Map(x => x.ChannelCode).Column("CHCD");
    Map(x => x.ShowCode).Column("SHOWCD");
    Map(x => x.ShowStartTime).Column("ONAIRSTART");
    Map(x => x.ShowEndTime).Column("ONAIREND");
    Map(x => x.Presenters).Column("HOST");
    Map(x => x.Guests).Column("GUEST");
    Map(x => x.Planners).Column("PLANNER");
    Map(x => x.ModifiedTime).Column("UPDDATE");

    HasMany(x => x.Pal)
            .AsBag()
            .Inverse()
            .KeyColumns.Add("PROGCD", "CHCD")
            .Cascade.All()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
}
```

DetailMap:

```
public ProgramDetailMap()
{
    Table("S_IDB_M_PROG_DTL");

    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ScriptNumber, "PROGCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ChannelCode, "CHCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ProductNumber, "PRODCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ColorCode, "COLORCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.SizeCode, "SIZECD");

    Map(x => x.PromoCode,"PCPARAM1");
    Map(x => x.EasyPayInstalments,"EZINST");
    Map(x => x.EasyPayFirstAmount,"EZAMT");
    Map(x => x.EasyPayNextAmount,"EZAMT2");
    Map(x => x.UpdatedDate).Column("UPDDATE");

    References(x => x.ProgramHeader)
        .Columns("PROGCD", "CHCD")
        .LazyLoad();

    References(x => x.Replay)
        .Columns("PROGCD", "CHCD", "PRODCD", "COLORCD", "SIZECD")
        .NotFound.Ignore();
}
```

}

Replay:

```
public ProgramReplayMap()
{
    Table("S_IDB_M_PROG_REPL");

    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ScriptNumber, "PROGCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ChannelCode, "CHCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ProductNumber, "PRODCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ColorCode, "COLORCD")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.SizeCode, "SIZECD");

    Map(x => x.Price, "REC_PRICE");
    Map(x => x.Postage, "REC_POSTAGE");
    Map(x => x.UpdatedDate).Column("UPDDATE");
}
```

Appreciate some response for this query.

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what "SELECT N+1" means?

Comment: Little bit. Say if there is a collection of some object and each object has got collection of another object i.e 1 to Many relation. SELECT N+1 is one select query for the main object and N additional select to get the collection. Hope this is right

Comment: Just want to know whether my mappings are right

Answer (score 0):

What you want as a starting point is to enable batch fetching. Documentation is at http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch

In FluentNHibernate it's available as the `.BatchSize()` methods on the ClassMap and on collection mappings.

Batch fetching means NHibernate can fetch a number of related instances of the same type in one go. For example, if you have loaded 20 instances of A that each hold a lazy reference to B, as soon as you access one of the B instances, NHibernate can load all 20 B instances using one query. The assumption is that if you access one of the referenced B instances, it's likely that you will soon access the other ones too, and that loading 20 instances using the same query is so fast that it doesn't matter much if we happen to load a few that are not actually needed. (The number 20 is what you control using the batch-size setting.)